# Error booting after Virtualbox VM upgrade

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I am using Vagrant and Homestead for laravel development. After updgrading my VM, when I `vagrant up` from Homestead root location I got an error:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead-7: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
==> homestead-7: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> homestead-7: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> homestead-7: Setting the name of the VM: homestead-7
==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> homestead-7: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    homestead-7: Adapter 1: nat
    homestead-7: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> homestead-7: Forwarding por`enter code here`ts...
    homestead-7: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 8025 (guest) => 8025 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 27017 (guest) => 27017 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> homestead-7: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> homestead-7: Booting VM...
==> homestead-7: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    homestead-7: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    homestead-7: SSH username: vagrant
    homestead-7: SSH auth method: private key
    homestead-7: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    homestead-7:
    homestead-7: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically repla                                                                ce
    homestead-7: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    homestead-7:
    homestead-7: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    homestead-7: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    homestead-7: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key.                                                                ..
==> homestead-7: Machine booted and ready!
==> homestead-7: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> homestead-7: Setting hostname...
==> homestead-7: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> homestead-7: Mounting shared folders...
    homestead-7: /vagrant => D:/Development/homestead
Vagrant was unable to mount VirtualBox shared folders. This is usually
because the filesystem "vboxsf" is not available. This filesystem is
made available via the VirtualBox Guest Additions and kernel module.
Please verify that these guest additions are properly installed in the
guest. This is not a bug in Vagrant and is usually caused by a faulty
Vagrant box. For context, the command attempted was:

mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 vagrant /vagrant

    enter code here

The error output from the command was:

: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The error message tells you what you need: "Please verify that these guest additions are properly installed in the guest."

Comment: come on man. It's machine generated and stackoverflow didn't warn me any error when i am posting. If you don't understand, then ask me. Giving up Programming ?? A good programmer said that..?? i don't think so.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42716556/5568965 Seems to be the same problem.